# Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths - for non-existant directory

Tags: magento2, cron, readiness-check

In ver 2.2.5 of Magento CE, var/log/update.log contains errors similar to:

```
update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found following non-writable paths:    /unqualified-path/magento2/.github [] []
```

But there is no such directory as magento2/.github !

There are a number of .github directories elsewhere, but the error persists even if I change their permissions to 777.

Additional info:
- shared server, I have no access to the account running Apache and cannot change ownership of the files to that account
- When first installed, using composer, the readiness check passed with no problem
- In general, both the frontend and the admin of Magento are working OK.

Answer (score 0):

Appears 2.2.4 or 2.2.5 has included the .github folder as a dependency in var/.setup_cronjob_status. We never had a .github folder in our Magento 2 install either!

To fix, go to https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2, download a copy, extract the .github folder and copy to the root of your Magento install.